# Protobuf float value transmission over TCP/IP and data corruption

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, protocol-buffers

I have two applications that communicate over TCP/IP written in C++ that use protobuf library to exchange data defined into a proto message.

**floatExample.proto**

```
syntax = "proto3";

message FloatMessage {
  optional float value = 1;
}
```

**serverFloatExample.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iomanip>
#include "floatExample.pb.h"

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
     socklen_t clilen;
     char buffer[1024];
     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
     int n;

     if (argc < 2) {
         fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
         exit(1);
     }

     // create a socket
     // socket(int domain, int type, int protocol)
     sockfd =  socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     if (sockfd < 0)
        error("ERROR opening socket");

     // clear address structure
     bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

     portno = atoi(argv[1]);

     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

     if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
     {
        error("ERROR on binding");
        return -1;
    }

     listen(sockfd,5);

     // The accept() call actually accepts an incoming connection
     clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);


     newsockfd = accept(sockfd,
                 (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
     if (newsockfd < 0) {
          error("ERROR on accept");
          return -1;
     }

    printf("server: got connection from %s port %d\n",
    inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(cli_addr.sin_port));

    while(true) 
    {
        sleep(2);
        bzero(buffer,1024);

        n = read(newsockfd,buffer,1024);
        if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
        {
            printf("Here is the message size: <%d>\n", n);
        }   

        FloatMessage receivedMsg = FloatMessage();
        receivedMsg.ParseFromString(buffer);

        printf("VALUE: <%.2f>\n", receivedMsg.value());
        receivedMsg.PrintDebugString();
    }

    close(newsockfd);
    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

**clientFloatExample.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include "floatExample.pb.h" 

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    char buffer[256];
    if (argc < 3) {
       fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
       exit(0);
    }
    portno = atoi(argv[2]);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
         (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
         server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
        error("ERROR connecting");

    FloatMessage float_message;
    float_message.set_value(1.0);  
    float_message.PrintDebugString();

    std::string serialized_message = float_message.SerializeAsString();

    n = write(sockfd, serialized_message.c_str(), serialized_message.size());
    if (n < 0) 
    {
        error("ERROR writing to socket");
    } 

    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

The bug is the following: sometimes some of the float values received by server application are not the same as the values transmitted by client application.

For example (using protobuf serialization):

- If Client application serialize floatValue = 1.0  --> Server Application deserialize 0 **(ERROR!)**
- If Client application serialize floatValue = 1.01  --> Server Application deserialize 1.01 (OK)
- If Client application serialize floatValue = 2.5  --> Server Application deserialize 0 **(ERROR!)**
- If Client application serialize floatValue = 2.51  --> Server Application deserialize 2.51 (OK)

Can anyone please suggest me where is the problem or help with this?

Comment: Time to pop open WireShark and see what you're actually sending.

Comment: You need to `read` until you have received the entire message.

Comment: @molbdnilo can you suggest me how to do?

Comment: Can you explain the reason for doing `std::string serialized_message = float_message.SerializeAsString();`, only to completely ignore it, and calling `SerializeAsString()` two more times, in the immediately-following `write()`?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik mistake. Code edited.

Comment: There are several things wrong with your code. (1) the `sleep()` is just a waste of time. (2) `bzero()` is unnecessary. (3) You are ignoring the case `n == 0`. (4) You aren't making any further use of `n`, e.g. when calling `receivedMsg.ParseFromString(buffer);`: that method should take a length parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line contains the problem:

```
receivedMsg.ParseFromString(buffer);
```

`ParseFromString` is documented as taking a `std::string&`, but you give it a `char*`. This invokes the `std::string::string(char*)` constructor that **only reads up to the first NUL byte**.

The correct solution is to just use the `ParseFromArray` method that takes a pointer and a size:

```
receivedMsg.ParseFromArray(buf, n);
```

Comment: Shoudn't be using `std::string` or `parseFromString()` at all actually, if the data is binary.

Comment: You're right. I missed the other Parse methods in MessageLite. ParseFromArray is the correct one to use. Will edit when I get home.

Comment: @Botje Thanks! the problem is the use of parseFromString(). The right way to decode binary data is the using of ParseFromArray()